# Excel Listbox not Populating Correctly

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have been following a tutorial and playing with developing Fully Automated User Data Entry Form.

The Video I followed PSB:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P53T6oxgUVA&ab_channel=TheDataLabs

After having downloaded his files and gone through the code step by step, I still get a yellow highlight over the particular section of the ELSE statement on the Sub Clear()? Additionally my Listbox does not update correctly it replaces the previous entry with the next entry saved.

Please view the code below

```
Sub Clear()

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = [Counta(Room Access 2!A:A)] '''Identify Last Row as per tutorial''

    With Frm_Room_Access_2

    .Surname_Txtbx.Value = ""
    .Rank_Cmbobx.Value = ""
    .Section_Txtbx.Value = ""
    .Extention_Txtbx.Value = ""
    .Service_Number_Txtbx.Value = ""
    .Due_Time_Txtbx.Value = ""
    .OpBtn_Time_as_Now.Value = False
    
    .SerialNo_Txtbx.Value = ""
    
    
    If iRow > 1 Then
    .List_Database.RowSource = "Room Access 2!A2:G" & iRow
    Else
    .List_Database.RowSource = "Room Access 2!A2:G" '''' Keeps Highlighting Error ''''
    
    End If
    
    End With

    End Sub



Sub Submit()

     Dim sh As Worksheet
     Dim iRow As Long

     Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Room Access 2")

     If Frm_Room_Access_2.SerialNo_Txtbx.Value = "" Then
        
     iRow = [Counta(Room Access 2!A:A)] + 1
     Else
     iRow = Frm_Room_Access_2.SerialNo_Txtbx.Value
     End If

     With sh

     .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 1
     .Cells(iRow, 2) = Frm_Room_Access_2.Surname_Txtbx.Value
     .Cells(iRow, 3) = Frm_Room_Access_2.Service_Number_Txtbx.Value
     .Cells(iRow, 4) = Frm_Room_Access_2.Rank_Cmbobx.Value
     .Cells(iRow, 5) = Frm_Room_Access_2.Section_Txtbx.Value
     .Cells(iRow, 6) = Frm_Room_Access_2.Extention_Txtbx.Value
     .Cells(iRow, 7) = IIf(Frm_Room_Access_2.OpBtn_Time_as_Now.Value = True And Frm_Room_Access_2.Due_Time_Txtbx.Value = "", Now(), Frm_Room_Access_2.Due_Time_Txtbx.Value)


     End With

     End Sub
```

The Issues that I want to resolve is firstly why is my list box not adding another entry under the first entry, it simply replaces the first entry upon saving. Do I require another method for this?

Secondly why is the code Highlighting that the Else Statement is incorrect despite following the tutorial and replicating the code correctly to my particular needs.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Room Access 2!A2:G" is not a valid range - it needs to be G something.

Comment: Probably `"Room Access 2!A2:G2"`

Comment: Don't how reliable that source is as COUNTA is not the best way to find the last blank row.

Comment: Thanks you, even when I try to use "G2" still flags and error

Comment: `"'Room Access 2'!A2:G2"` ?

Comment: I tried that and nothing

Comment: Right thank you for all your advice, the issue was from the Sheet name "Room Access 2". I renamed it to Room_Access_2 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The last cell with text in a column can be found with

```
Range("B" & 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

The Offset(1, 0) selects the cell below in order for you to copy data to it.

To select a worksheet use:

```
Worksheets("Room Access 2").Select
```

No underlines are needed.